# Chaining two containers with docker

Tags: iptables, nat, docker, containers

I have two containers that I have chained them together, so traffic that comes to container 2, first passes by container 1. I set container 2 --net=none.

Host --- Container 1 --- Container 2

this is what I did:

```
CONE=$(docker run --privileged -i -t -p 801:80 CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash)
CTWO=$(docker run --privileged -i -t -p 800:80 --net=none CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash)


pipework br1 $CONE 10.1.0.1/8
pipework br1 $CTWO 10.1.0.2/8

docker exec -ti $CONE apt-get install -y iptables
docker exec -ti $CONE iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
docker exec -ti $CTWO ip route add default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth1
docker exec -ti $CTWO ping www.google.com #PING OKAY
```

So everything works fine, however from host I cannot ping container 2, but vice versa is possible.

IP forwarding is enabled in host so:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
returns 1
```

This is routing table for CONE:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.42.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

This is routing table for CTWO:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth1
```

This is routing table for Host:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

What should I do to be able ping container 2?

Comment: What do the route tables inside one say, possibly it thinks it needs to go through the host to get to two?

Comment: I've put the routing tales up there in the description.

Comment: So, if you cannot ping `CTWO` from the host, I'm thinking you may need a route in the host via `172.17.42.1` ?

Comment: There is a route to 172.17.42.1 (docker0 bridge), so host can ping eth0 of CONE (which is 172.17.0.7) but it can't ping eth1 (which is 10.1.0.1)

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't you have a route to `10.0.0.0 via 172.17.42.1`,  otherwise how is your host going to know that `10.0.0.0` is anywhere (as far as it knows it's available via `192.168.1.1`)?

Comment: Okay after adding `route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 172.17.42.1` in the host, I can ping `10.1.0.1` which is CONE, but I can't ping `10.1.0.2` which is CTWO.

Comment: You probably need some further MASQUERADE rules, it's been so long since I've set up NAT in iptables..